# How do i check if two values exist in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I am working on a poll system where each user can vote once per poll. If they submit their vote it will be inserted in the [polls_results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxzqQ.png)

To check if a user already submitted a vote i made an sql query that selects * from the table polls_results and puts the result in a array:

```php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM polls_results';
$result = mysqli_query( $db, $query );
$array = array();
    
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) {
    array_push( $array, $row );
}
```

This is the output of the array with my current table data.

```
Array
(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [result_id] => 132
                [poll_id] => 16
                [user_id] => 2
                [vote] => 0
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [result_id] => 133
                [poll_id] => 17
                [user_id] => 2
                [vote] => 0
            )
    
        [2] => Array
            (
                [result_id] => 131
                [poll_id] => 16
                [user_id] => 1
                [vote] => 1
            )
    
)
```

My question is how do i check if a submitted vote exists in my multidimensional array?

I already tried it with two array_search functions in a if-statement but then it only checks if a `user_id` and `poll_id` exist in the array. But i want it to check if there's an item with those two combined.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be great if you can paste the code inline into the question instead of linking to images. Maybe you also read the text about an [mre].

Comment: Okey thanks! I made the code inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a user already voted you can also use SQL instead of the checking inside PHP, I suppose.

So maybe checking the `user_id`, `poll_id` and `vote` like this:

```php
$userId = 1;
$pollId = 2;

$query = "SELECT * FROM `polls_results` WHERE `user_id`={$userId} AND `poll_id`={$pollId} AND `vote`=NULL";
```

would be better approach. If there is a result returned then the user does not have voted.

If 0=no and 1=yes, then I would suggest using `NULL` as default value for the `vote` column. So if the `vote` column is `NULL`, it means that the user did not vote at all. I updated my query to check for this.

Please be aware that you should sanitize `$userId` and `$pollId` so that no SQL-injection happens. You should check [PHP prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thanks! But the vote column in my database is for a yes or a no... 0 means they voted no and 1 means they voted yes. What do i need to change in the query then?

Comment: I updated my answer to help you with that case.

Comment: Okey i changed the "AND vote = NULL" part to "AND vote != ' '" And now it works! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad you could figure it out. Yes, checking for an empty string `vote != ' '` could also be a solution. If you liked my answer mark as answer or up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

@codedge SQL solution is probably the preferred solution for your case, but here is a simple example of how to search the array:

```php
function getVote(array $votes, int $userId, int $pollId): ?int
{
    foreach ($votes as $vote) {
        if ($vote['user_id'] === $userId && $vote['poll_id'] === $pollId) {
            return $vote['vote'];
        }
    }

    return null;
}

$vote = getVote($votesArray, 1, 16);
```